# opendaylight: how to deploy different applications on different switches?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I am using Oendaylight (carbon) to develop an SDN application consisting of multiple switches that connect to a controller. I want to be able to deploy different applications on different switches when they connect. How can I specify this? For example when openflow:1 connects, I want to deploy an L2 switch on it and when openflow:2 connects, I want to deploy a different application on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not deploy applications on switches. Applications run on controller, you can add a logic which programs selected switches only.

What you essentially want to do is reactive programming; wait for events and act accordingly. This can be easily achieved by hooking the event listeners to the nodes in YANG model of the application. Any change in these nodes will be then notified to your application which can then do selective network programming.

In the example mentioned, you will need to use "InstanceIdentifier" object to identify which data model's events you are interested in listening.

```
InstanceIdentifier<Node> nodeID = InstanceIdentifier.builder(Nodes.class).child(Node.class, new NodeKey(node.getId()))                        .augmentation(FlowCapableNode.class)
.build();
```

Now simply register a listener to this IID by using DataBroker object's registerDataChangeListener method.

```
db.registerDataChangeListener(LogicalDatastoreType.CONFIGURATION, nodeID, this, AsyncDataBroker.DataChangeScope.SUBTREE);
```

At this point in time, you will be notified of any update (addition/modifification/deletion) of the switches you have registered for.

Finally to catch the event use/override DataChangeListener interface's onDataChanged method and add your fancy logic.

The similar logic can be fine grained to listen to activities on particular flow tables, flow rules, etc on the switch.

Comment: On a side note, DataChangeListener is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release so use DataTreeChangeListener.

Comment: This works for new code that you may want to write but what if I want to selectively install an existing application such as L2 switch? Is there a way I can  have a master listener that gets control and passes this event upstream? Right now L2switch runs on every connected switch which is not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: An application like learning switch is meant to work for the entire network, essentially. If I were to do selective MAC learning and other l2switch features, I will use l2switch's APIs in ODL and make a new application that takes input from upstream for selective listening and passes it back when such an event occurs.
It wouldn't take much time to make such stuff. Besides, I am not aware of any application in ODL that does selective programming out of the box. Certain tweaks are always required.

Comment: The facilities for application composition are limited in this case. I want a multiplexer to run on a particular switch but L2 switch installs itself everywhere. I thought it would be possible to support application composition and re-use in a more architecturally consistent way.

Comment: It might go as a improvement on L2switch project. Or a new feature suggestion. 
For your purpose, you can write a simple python script which just makes the REST calls for installing the rules for the selected switches. The URL will look like [link] (http://127.0.0.1:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:2)

Comment: Not sure I understand the suggestion. l2switch is a java application that gets invoked and installs reactive rules when a switch connects. What I want is for it to be aware that it should only install rules on the specific switches that I specify and on the tables that I specify. How does this suggestion work in that case? Thanks.

Comment: @TomPantelis  What will DataChangeListener be replaced with (please share if you know)?  ODL is plagued by sudden changes in architecture and deprecation without guidance on alternatives.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is replaced by DataTreeChangeListener. DataChangeListener has been deprecated since the Carbon release. The javadocs indicate this. It was also in the release notes (End-of-life section): http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-carbon/release-notes/projects/controller.html